# Implementing decltype in C++98

Tags: c++, decltype

I was wondering if there is a way for implementing the C++11 operator `decltype` using just C++98 features.

I mean something like

```
template<class Func>
struct decl_type{
    typedef Func() type;
};
```

Obviously, my code does not compile.

Comment: in addition: [Boost.Typeof](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/typeof.html)

Comment: There's [Boost.Typeof](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/typeof.html), but I would assume this requires compiler intrinsics to implement.

Comment: Intuitively, they cannot portably be a way, otherwise it won't have been standardized.

Comment: @Angew Apparently there's some sort of ["registration"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/typeof/tuto.html) required for user-defined types for the pure library solution. Not sure if it defers to compiler intrinsics if supported.

Comment: quite old question. However, here is a implementation of [a portable "typeof" operator](http://www.drdobbs.com/a-portable-typeof-operator/184401310)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really *implement* the `decltype` since it is not really a function, but a compiler keyword, as you can't implement, for example, `return` or `auto`. Actually, `decltype(...)`, somewhat similarly to `auto`, is replaced with the result typename by the c++ preprocessor, because, unlike, for example, Haskell or Javascript, you cannot have a type itself stored in a value. But you can overload a function multiple times, so you have something like

```cpp
void declt(int a) {
    typedef int type;
}
void declt(char a) {
    typedef char type;
}
...
```